# No replies for 30 seconds: exiting during bulk insertion in Redis 5

Tags: redis

Migrating Redis from 2.6 to 5.17 and facing issue during bulk insert of data , the same data gets loaded fine in Redis 2.6 but fails in Redis 5+ with No replies for 30 seconds.
I checked on different content around seems like a issue with redis pipe usage , i can see even the last line of the bulk data is loaded in to redis but yet it fails to ack back with in 30 secs .
Note : Redis with persistance turned off

Can someone please help with a possible solution for this or an alternate way for Redis Bulk insertion .